# how to union two querys in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have 2 querys in codeigniter,am using for ajax data tables those querys. Before that it will worked when i use single 
query. After adding one more query for UNION it is not working for me. Please find my model functions using for 
data tables.

### Model.php (Working this function)Using single query in _get_online_supplier_reports_datatable() function

```
<?php
public function _get_online_supplier_reports_datatable(){

     $this->db->select('"Amadeus" AS SupplierName,TST_Type,TKT_Type,TKTNumber,TKT_FO_REF,BasePrice,TaxPrice,Commission1,(BasePrice+TaxPrice) AS TotalPrice,"issued" AS tkt_type,createdby,TicketedDate as created_date,CONCAT(a3m.firstname," ",a3m.lastname) AS created_name,a3m.account_id,a3m.locationvalue AS Location_ID,a3m.locationdescription AS Location_Name,a3m.costcentervalue AS CostCenter_ID,a3m.costcenterdescription AS CostCenter_Name');
        $this->db->from($this->traveldb->database.".booking_price bp");
        $this->db->join('a3m_account_details a3m','a3m.account_id=createdby','left');
        $this->db->where('TKTNumber !=', '');


        if(isset($_POST['order'])) // here order processing
        {
            $this->db->order_by($this->column_order_online_supplier_reports_match[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);
        } 
        else if(isset($this->order_online_supplier_reports_match))
        {
            $order = $this->order_online_supplier_reports_match;
            $this->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order)]);
        }

    }

    public function get_online_supplier_reports_datatable(){
        $this->_get_online_supplier_reports_datatable();
        if($_POST['length'] != -1)
        $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);
        $query = $this->db->get();
         return $query->result();
    }
    public function count_filtered_online_supplier_reports_rec(){
        $this->_get_online_supplier_reports_datatable();
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->num_rows();
    } 

    ?>
```

I have added One more query in _get_online_supplier_reports_datatable() function for Union both querys .after that it is not working

```
<?php
public function _get_online_supplier_reports_datatable(){

        //Query 1 here
        $this->db->select('"Amadeus" AS SupplierName,TST_Type,TKT_Type,TKTNumber,TKT_FO_REF,BasePrice,TaxPrice,Commission1,(BasePrice+TaxPrice) AS TotalPrice,"issued" AS tkt_type,createdby,TicketedDate as created_date,CONCAT(a3m.firstname," ",a3m.lastname) AS created_name,a3m.account_id,a3m.locationvalue AS Location_ID,a3m.locationdescription AS Location_Name,a3m.costcentervalue AS CostCenter_ID,a3m.costcenterdescription AS CostCenter_Name');
        $this->db->from($this->traveldb->database.".booking_price bp");
        $this->db->join('a3m_account_details a3m','a3m.account_id=createdby','left');
        $this->db->where('TKTNumber !=', '');
        $query1 = $this->db->get_compiled_select(); 

        //QUery2 Here
         $this->db->select('"Amadeus" AS SupplierName,"" AS TST_Type,"" AS  TKT_Type,br_tkt AS TKTNumber,"" as TKT_FO_REF,br_fare_paid_B as BasePrice,br_tax_refund_TXT as TaxPrice,br_cancellation_penalty as Commission1,br_fare_total_RFT AS TotalPrice,br_cancel_type AS tkt_type,br_added_by as createdby,br_refund_date as created_date,CONCAT(a3m.firstname," ",a3m.lastname) AS created_name,a3m.account_id,a3m.locationvalue AS Location_ID,a3m.locationdescription AS Location_Name,a3m.costcentervalue AS CostCenter_ID,a3m.costcenterdescription AS CostCenter_Name');
        $this->db->from($this->traveldb->database.".booking_refund bp");
        $this->db->join('a3m_account_details a3m','a3m.account_id=br_added_by','left');
        $this->db->where('br_tkt !=', '');
        $query2 = $this->db->get_compiled_select(); 

    //Union both querys 
     $query=  $this->db->query($query1." UNION ALL".$query2);

        if(isset($_POST['order'])) // here order processing
        {
            $this->db->order_by($this->column_order_online_supplier_reports_match[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);
        } 
        else if(isset($this->order_online_supplier_reports_match))
        {
            $order = $this->order_online_supplier_reports_match;
            $this->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order)]);
        }

    }

    public function get_online_supplier_reports_datatable(){
        $this->_get_online_supplier_reports_datatable();
        if($_POST['length'] != -1)
        $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);
        $query = $this->db->get();
         return $query->result();
    }
    public function count_filtered_online_supplier_reports_rec(){
        $this->_get_online_supplier_reports_datatable();
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->num_rows();
    }
```

The main probelm is when am using union there will  be getting data but i dont want to get data their only. Just i want to
union both 2 querys . My required Out put function _get_online_supplier_reports_datatable()   is like this code.

```
public function _get_online_supplier_reports_datatable(){

        //Query 1 here
        $query1= $this->db->select('"Amadeus" AS SupplierName,TST_Type,TKT_Type,TKTNumber,TKT_FO_REF,BasePrice,TaxPrice,Commission1,(BasePrice+TaxPrice) AS TotalPrice,"issued" AS tkt_type,createdby,TicketedDate as created_date,CONCAT(a3m.firstname," ",a3m.lastname) AS created_name,a3m.account_id,a3m.locationvalue AS Location_ID,a3m.locationdescription AS Location_Name,a3m.costcentervalue AS CostCenter_ID,a3m.costcenterdescription AS CostCenter_Name');
        $this->db->from($this->traveldb->database.".booking_price bp");
        $this->db->join('a3m_account_details a3m','a3m.account_id=createdby','left');
        $this->db->where('TKTNumber !=', '');

        //$query1 = $this->db->get_compiled_select(); 

        //QUery2 Here
        $query2=  $this->db->select('"Amadeus" AS SupplierName,"" AS TST_Type,"" AS  TKT_Type,br_tkt AS TKTNumber,"" as TKT_FO_REF,br_fare_paid_B as BasePrice,br_tax_refund_TXT as TaxPrice,br_cancellation_penalty as Commission1,br_fare_total_RFT AS TotalPrice,br_cancel_type AS tkt_type,br_added_by as createdby,br_refund_date as created_date,CONCAT(a3m.firstname," ",a3m.lastname) AS created_name,a3m.account_id,a3m.locationvalue AS Location_ID,a3m.locationdescription AS Location_Name,a3m.costcentervalue AS CostCenter_ID,a3m.costcenterdescription AS CostCenter_Name');
        $this->db->from($this->traveldb->database.".booking_refund bp");
        $this->db->join('a3m_account_details a3m','a3m.account_id=br_added_by','left');
        $this->db->where('br_tkt !=', '');

        //$query2 = $this->db->get_compiled_select(); 

    //Union both querys 
     $query=  $this->db->query($query1." UNION ALL".$query2);

        if(isset($_POST['order'])) // here order processing
        {
            $this->db->order_by($this->column_order_online_supplier_reports_match[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);
        } 
        else if(isset($this->order_online_supplier_reports_match))
        {
            $order = $this->order_online_supplier_reports_match;
            $this->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order)]);
        }

    }
```

Comment: can you show us error ?

Comment: `No tables used

SELECT * LIMIT 100`

Comment: can you tell me output of $query1 and $query2 ?

Comment: `$query= $this->db->query($query1." UNION ALL ".$query2)->result();` after using this am getting `No tables used SELECT * LIMIT 100`. I want without `get_compiled_select()` adding union 2 querys

Comment: why are you used this UNION ALL with two same query?

Comment: you've to use `get_compiled_select()` - why do you even consider to reject that method ?

Comment: second thing your UNION ALL will not work if both table have differnt count of columns

Comment: Both tables same columns.

Comment: @sintakonte Already in sub function am using get method to get all records . If i use `get_compiled_select()` again am using get in another function once see